# Passing parameters in jQuery

Tags: jquery

What i have is working, so I'm just asking if there's a more elegant way to do this.  I have:

```
<form method="post" action="15Action.cfm">
<p><input id="A" name="A1"></p>
<p><input id="B" name="B1"></p>
<p><input id="C" name="C1"></p>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

If the changes either A or B, then concatenate the two fields together and place them into C.
What I have is:

```
function doit(A,B) {
   return A+B;
};
$(function() {
   var A = $('#A');
   var B = $('#B');
  $('#A, #B').change(function() {
  $('#C').val(doit(A.val(),B.val()));
  });
});
```

I wonder if I should write

```
$('#C').val(doit(A,B))
```

instead, or is it acceptable to pass A.val(), B.val()?

Comment: It looks like you edited your original code to reflect the changes suggested by Kyle. I think it would be more helpful to others who come across this question if you had left your original code as it was. Otherwise Kyle's answer doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if I should write
>
> ```
> $('#C').val(doit(A,B))
> ```
>
> instead, or is it acceptable to pass A.val(), B.val()?

Passing `A,B` wouldn't work. Your solution looks reasonably elegant, you even cache the jQuery objects to get A,B in the closures you use.

you could make it a little more concise by doing:

```
function doit(A,B) {
   return A+B;
};
$(function() {
   var A = $('#A');
   var B = $('#B');
   $('#A, #B').change(function() {
      $('#C').val(doit(A.val(),B.val()));
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle!  I noticed that after I had asked the question, and you are right in pointing that out!  I edited the question so that the discussion would stay focused on the passing parameters subject.

Answer (score 1):

Either way is fine really... What it depends on is what kind of params you expect to always be passed to `doit`. If you paln on olny doingit with jQuery objects (read elements) then i might jsut passin in selectors to `doit` and do all my lookups in there - or you could pass the jQuery objects themselves as this wouldnt make much of a difference.

```
function doit(a,b){
  return $(a).val()+$(b).val();
}

// these are then functionally equiv.
doit('#A','#B');
doit($('#A'), $('#B'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If inside `doit()` you need the values of A and B, both methods are the same. I would leave your code as it is.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're doing is concatenating the two values, I would not even bother with a `doit()` function and just glue the two values together.

```
$(function() {
   $('#A, #B').change(function() {
      $('#C').val($('#A').val() + $('#B').val());
   });
});
```

Comment: Elegant.  Perhaps I should ask the question again with a more involved scenario to justify making a function call and passing parameters.